# Should my case classes have collections from my associations?

Tags: scala, slick

If I have a case class that looks like:

```
case class User(id: Int, name: String, addresses: Seq[Address])

case class Address(id: Int, userId: Int, name: String)
```

Should I remove the addresses property from User when I am using slick or can I still include it?

I have never really used associations in slick before so a little confused.

Comment: I hope that I'm not stating the obvious(IDK your programming background). Those are classes of objects you'd like to have (in your application). Most relational databases don't support objects, they manipulate with rows, that are flat. That means that your Slick classes that represent your rows in database must be flat (no sequences, trees etc).

Comment: The relation that you are showing is 1:N (one user has many addresses). So you would do a full join (if user must have at least one address) or left join (if it can have zero or more addresses). And then you'd get `Seq[(User, Address)]` => group by `User` and make your domain objects like you specified. See [here](http://olivebh.com/scala-play-slick.html) for more details.

Comment: Here is the talk for more info about modelling in slick  http://youtube.com/watch?v=ciyjJLYIySY

Comment: You should model depending on your use case ! If you know that having a user without adresses does not make any sense then adresses should belong to user. It means that you will have to join your user and your address table every time you fetch a user (or multiple users). On the other hand, if sometimes you want to fetch the users without their addresses, create two distinct case classes : `User` and `UserWithAdresses`.

Answer (score 3):

## Slick is not ORM

So, Slick does not support nested objects like hibernate. If you strongly want to have nested objects model Slick is not a suitable solution for your use case. This point is explicitly mentioned in the slick documentation as well.

Your use case in Slick is modeled like this

```
case class User(id: Int, name: String) //id is the primary key 

case class Address(id: Int, name: String) //id is the primary key

case class UserAddresses(userId: Int, addressId: Int) //userId, addressId are the foreign keys.
```

Each of the above case class requests a table in database and `UserAddresses` table establishes the association between the User and the Address. So, for one user you can have one or more address ids in the user addresses table (typical relation database way of modelling one to many relationship between entities)

UserAddresses captures the one-many relationship between User and Address

*Note that above design looks like the typical database design one would choose to do in case of one-many relationship. In Slick these models represents relational tables. So, for each table we need to have one model which represents that table in code. Slick helps in writing sql agnostic, composable, reusable, typesafe and scala collection like queries. So end of the day Slick code looks like Scala collections manipulation code.*

Comment: so I need to create 3 slick table objects then and treat UserAddresses as if it is another table?

Comment: Is there something like JPA in scala? I tried anorm, slick, scalalikejdbc. None of them can provide smth similar to JPA... (((

Comment: @pamu is it mature and supported enough? Seems like project abandoned